# How to make a stored procedure return the last inserted id

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Here I have a stored procedure that inserts a row but how do you make it return the last inserted id without making another query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertCriteriaItem]
@GroupID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into CriteriaItem (CriteriaGroupID) VALUES(@GroupID)
    --I don't want to make another query here
END
```

Is it possible to do this

Comment: and why don't you want to make another query after the insert?  I assume you're specifically referring to `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using Sql Server you can make use of the [OUTPUT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause.

Something like

```
DECLARE @CriteriaItem TABLE (
        ID INT IDENTITY (1,1),
        CriteriaGroupID INT
)
insert into @CriteriaItem (CriteriaGroupID)
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES(1)
```

Answer (score 8):

dunno what your deal is without having an extra query, but if you want data from a database, you have to query it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertCriteriaItem]
@GroupID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into CriteriaItem (CriteriaGroupID) VALUES(@GroupID);
    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to make another query?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertCriteriaItem]
@GroupID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    insert into CriteriaItem (CriteriaGroupID) VALUES(@GroupID);
    SELECT @@IDENTITY AS InsertedId;
END
```